# Run Bash script on the Windows XP command line

Tags: windows-xp

How do I create a file and run a Bash script on the Windows XP command line?

I only know commands in Linux. :)

Answer (score 7):

Windows doesn't use the [Bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29) shell, so therefore it has no Bash scripting. You could use [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) to run a virtual Linux environment within Windows.

What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm doing a Slony replication on two different servers (with databases,ofcourse), but with different OS [Ubuntu and WinXP]. The problem is, I have to run a slonik script on both servers to make the replication work. hmm.

Comment: Is it possible to run bash scripts in Cygwin?

Comment: `Cygwin is not supported on this Windows version.` on XP.

Answer (score 7):

Two ways to go.

If you want a quick light wieght solution install "Unix Shell Utilities" which features a bourne shell inplementation and most of the basic unix command line tools (sed , grep awk etc).
This will work only if you have a simple script and use the command line tools in a very basic standard way.

Or as the other posters suggest install cygwin (this is a pretty major install!) which will give you a complete *nix environment on your PC, or "mingw" which is a stripped down cygwyn with just enough functionality to run the gcc compiler family but might be enough for your needs.

Comment: One funny thing is that I've seen a full Cygwin setup be much bigger than a full Linux setup, at times.

Answer (score 4):

I used [GNU Bash](http://www.steve.org.uk/Software/bash/) + [GNU Win32 utilities](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/). That's much simpler than installing [Cygwin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin), and GNU utilities contain useful tools like [sed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed), [cat](http://ss64.com/bash/cat.html), [Netpbm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm), etc.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of at least 4 ways to create a file from the windows console.  The most appropriate will depend on what you're doing and in what context.

You don't generally run bash scripts in windows.  It's just not a bash shell.  You run *batch* scripts, which is a completely different language, or PowerShell scripts (if it's installed).  You can run a script with some bash commands if you take the time to install something like [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) (which might be a good idea, given your background).